# Can you enforce that a component can only be used under a certain context provider in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

The title sums it up. Is there any way to type expected available context for a component so it TS errors if you use a component outside the context provider using typescript?

```
const MyContext = createContext<string>(undefined!);

const Consumer = () => {
  const text = useContext(MyContext);
  return <div>{text}</div>;
};

const WithProvider = () => (
  <MyContext.Provider value={"test"}>
    <Consumer />
  </MyContext.Provider>
);

const Without = () => <Consumer />;
```

I want WithProvider to work, and Without to throw a TS error.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, please explain more

Comment: This is not possible (as far as I know).  There can be any amount of components in between the `Consumer` and the `Provider` so how would the `Consumer` be able to look all the way up the tree?  `Without` is perfectly valid if you call `<Without/>` inside of a `Provider`.

Comment: Components could be made to express the context they require. They can know what child components the can render are, so they would emit as their requirements the union of their own specified context, and the context requirements emitted by their children.